# Multiple page links generated when editing a link for the side navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

This error happened at the subsite upon saving while trying to edit a link at the side navigation. This resulted in generating the same link multiple times. Any idea what might possibly cause the error and resolve the error?

Example:

Biz Engagement

Biz Engagement

Biz Engagement

Biz Engagement

Benefits

Home

Documents

Biz Engagement

^Pages

    Biz Engagement

Site contents

Furthermore, we weren't able to delete the extra links (i.e. the save function is not working as expected.)
Deleting using power shell is one option, but is there any way to delete from the front end?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, have you made any special settings? Try to delete it in site settings-->Look and Feel, whether it can be successful.

Comment: Thanks. That’s work, though we are still not entirely sure why the links got duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to share how we resolve it:

1. Go to Site Settings > Navigation
2. On the Navigation Settings > Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting
3. Select the item you want to delete and click the Delete function

Cheers!